# Как через декоратор можно добавить loader

Tags: angular2, typescript

Есть код

```
@loader('loadProducts')
    onPageChange(page: number = 1) {
        this.loader.start(); - Вот эту  строку добавить через декоратор
        this.productService.setPage(page);
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((ngx: NgxPaginator<Product>) => {
            this.productService.paginator = ngx;
            this.loader.finish(); - и вот эту
        });
    }
```

Возможно ли это вообще сделать и как, подскажите хотя бы где почитать.

Декоратор:

```
function loader(id) {    
    return function (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {

    }
}
```

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _лоадером_? Что должна делать эта аннотация `@loader('loadProducts')`?

Comment: функция которая меняет внутри себя переменную true или false @loader - это декоратор

Comment: декоратор - декорирует метод или свойство, то есть ты можешь выполнить код _до_, _после_, но не во время выполнения метода. То есть вызвать `this.loader.start();` перед основным телом, ты сможешь, а вот `this.loader.finish();`  внутри обработчика уже будет проблематично, если вообще возможно

Comment: поэтому и спрашиваю, как то внедрить в асинхронную функцию дополнительный вызов можно или нет.  Может кто то знает что то.

Comment: @Grundy читал там как то через рефлекшен можно переписать код функции, найти subscribe и между последней точкой с запятой и скобкой вставить код

Comment: Где читал например?

Comment: @Grundy если б  я вспомнил ... Попробую на английском задать вопрос, или найти ответ.

Comment: В общем максимум можно только вернуть из функции подписку, и в декораторе подписаться еще раз и выполнить нужную строку

Comment: @Grundy onPageChange -  должен быть observable ?

Comment: либо `Promise`.